# Auto check child when parent is checked in javascript + php laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i had a problem which is when parent is ticked , then the child is automatically checked .
Image
[image]

my code

```
<tbody id="catRecord">
   @php $catCode = ""; @endphp
   @if(!empty($data))
   @foreach($data as $i=>$cat)
   @if($cat->cc_category_code != $catCode )
   @if(isset($cat->irel__ref_category))
   <tr class="c_row">
      <td style='width: 300px;'>
         @for($j=0; $j<$cat->irel__ref_category->Ct_Level; $j++)
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
         @endfor
         <a href="#" class="crudlink"> - {{ $cat->irel__ref_category->Ct_Abbreviation }}</a>  // parent data
      </td>
      <td style='width: 600px;'>{{ $cat->irel__ref_category->Ct_Description }}</td> //child data
      <td style='width: 20px;'><input type="checkbox" class="ss" name="ss[]" id="ss[]" value="{{ $cat->irel__ref_category->Ct_Code }}^{{ $cat->irel__ref_category->Ct_Abbreviation }}^{{ $cat->irel__ref_category->Ct_Description }}" />
      </td> 
      <input type="hidden" id="cat[]" name="cat[]"  value="{{ $cat->irel__ref_category->Ct_Code }}" />
   </tr>
   @endif
   @endif
   @php  $catCode = $cat->cc_category_code;     @endphp
   @endforeach
   @endif
</tbody>
```

I cant find a way because because the data was fetched in table using php , I had refer other post but seems still cant find the way,I hope someone can give some idea . Sorry if my explaination not clear

Comment: can you show html generated ? Also code which you have tried ?

Comment: how to check what is the parent of the child? any similar to parent_id field?